# How to create an auto updater for browser extensions/addons?

Tags: process, add-on, auto-update

I need to create an auto-updater on clients computer that will automatically update
a particular addon on Internet Explorer, Firefox, ...
Of course user previously agrees that there will be automatic updates on his computer.

Do you guys have any idea where I could start to do this ?

I started thinking about running a process on the client side that with ask our 
server every couple of hours if there is a new version and then do the necessary 
update on the client side.

The idea is to update our addon on multiple browsers without prompting the user of a new version.

Is there any tools that you could recommend ? Thank you for the help.

Edit: I can use Firefox and Chrome 'updateURL' in the manifest. But how do I automatically update a BHO (IE extension), and a Safari extension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome have a built-in extension updater, an extension shouldn't bring its own. The updater works by periodically checking a particular URL for information on the current extension version. Firefox documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#updateURL. Chrome documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html.

Comment: The idea is to have one updater for all browser, Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari. It's rather easy to auto-update for Firefox and Chrome. I can do like you said using the manifest 'updateUrl', but my main concern is for Internet Explorer and Safari. Do I need a process running on the client to update a BHO (extension) ?

Comment: Safari add-ons can be updated automatically as well: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UpdatingExtensions/UpdatingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH12-SW1. Only IE doesn't have a built-in update mechanism, there you would need a separate process or (better) a task scheduler entry.

Comment: Thank you, very appreciated, i'll investigate on that.

Comment: http://crossrider.com/ have a great JS API to developer cross browser extensions and also have internal update mechanism for the developer code.
As long the changes are only code changes, they have internal HTTP based updates